# Legend hides chart created using JFreeChart

Tags: jscrollpane, jfreechart, legend

i've to create a chart using library `JFreeChart`, i try this:

```
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();    
ArrayList<MyObject> list = this.FillArray();
MyObject tmp;
String date[];
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
       tmp = list.get(i);
       ArrayList<MyObject1> obj = this.FillArray1(tmp);
       TimeSeries pop = new TimeSeries(tmp.getName(),Day.class);
       for(MyObject1 ob1 : obj){
          date = ob1.getDate().split("-");
          Day day = new Day(Integer.parseInt(date[0]), Integer.parseInt(date[1]), Integer.parseInt(date[2]));
          pop.addOrUpdate(day, ob1.getValue());

       }
       dataset.addSeries(pop);
    }
```

My problem borns when the number of object is very high and legend will cover the panelchart. What can i do? is possible to add a scrollpane to the legend?

Answer (score 1):

Legends are rendered in a `LegendTitle`, the first `Title` added to `List subtitles` when the `JFreeChart` instance is constructed with the `createLegend` parameter set to `true`. Because `JFreeChart` is not a `Container`, nor is `Title` a `Component`, adding a `LegendTitle` to a `JScrollPane` is not supported.

You can always invoke `getLegendItems()` and render the items in a `Scrollable` `Container` such as `JList` or `JTable`. To avoid duplication, set `createLegend` to `false`.